# Having trouble understanding the proof that $D_{n}$ is nonabelian for $n \geq 3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I saw a proof that $D_{n}$ is nonabelian for $n \geq 3$ that went the following way:

> Let $a,b$ are arbitrary elements of $D_{n}$. Suppose to the contrary that $ab = ba$. Then, we must have that $ab = ba \, \implies \, abb^{-1} = bab^{-1} \, \implies \, a = bab^{-1} = a^{-1}$. Therefore, $a^{2} = e$, and so $n \leq 2$.

There are two things about this proof that I do not understand:

1. How does $a = bab^{-1}$ imply that $bab^{-1} = a^{-1}$? I have tried multiplying $ab=ba$ on both sides by $a^{-1}$s and $b^{-1}$s, and still cannot derive that $a^{-1}=bab^{-1}$. Could someone show me algebraically and in detail where this comes from?
2. Also, why does $a^{2} = e$ imply that $n \leq 2$?

Could somebody please answer and explain these things to me?

Thank you.

Comment: You really have to tell us what facts about $a$ and $b$ you knew beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is not quite correct, but it can be fixed. Let us suppose that the definition of $D_n$ you have to work with, is that $D_n$ is the group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon. Let $r$ denote a rotation of $2\pi/n$ about the center of  the $n$-gon, and let $s$ denote a reflection in a line passing through the center of the $n$-gon.

Then the order of $r$ is $n$, and $r$ and $s$ satisfy the following relation

$$ sr = r^{-1}s.$$

The best way to understand this relation is to try to imagine how both the left and right side act on the regular $n$-gon. To do $sr$, is to first rotate by $2\pi/n$ and reflect by $s$, and to do $r^{-1}s$ is to first reflect, and then rotate by $2\pi/n$ in the opposite direction.

We could formally prove the relation in the following way. Let the $n$-gon sit with its center at the origin of the complex plane, and $r$ be the map $z\mapsto e^{2\pi i/n}z$ and $s$ be the map $z\mapsto\overline{z}$. Its not too hard to see that $r$ does indeed represent a rotation of $2\pi/n$ radians about the origin, and the complex conjugation map $s$ represents reflection in the real axis.

Then the following computation proves the relation:

$$\overline{e^{2\pi i/n}z} = e^{-2\pi i/n} \overline{z},$$

since $r^{-1}$ is represented by multiplying by the complex number $e^{-2\pi/n}$.

Now that we know that the order of $r$ is $n$, and that $sr=r^{-1}s$, we can proceed with the proof. Suppose that $D_n$ is abelian. Then it must be true that $ab=ba$ for all $a,b\in D_n$. In particular, $rs=sr$. We already know that $sr=r^{-1}s$, hence $rs = r^{-1}s$.

Cancelling $s$ yields $r=r^{-1}$, hence $r^2=e$. Hence the order of $r$ is at most 2. However we know that the order of $r$ is $n$, hence $n\leq 2$.

It follows that $D_n$ is nonabelian when $n\geq 3$.

Comment: I believe that in order to use this, I would first need to prove that $r$ and $s$ are the generators of $D_{n}$, wouldn't I?

Comment: As long as you know that they are elements of $D_n$ its fine.

Comment: Of course, the precise structure of your proof will depend on the definition of $D_n$ you have been given.

Comment: @JessyCat they could not generate the whole set and the proof would still be fine (although it can be shown that they do).

There isn't a standard definition of $D_n$ so you'd have to tell us which one you're working with

Comment: The answer can only be made more proof-like if we know exactly what the definition of $D_n$ you're working with is.

Comment: The group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon, including rotations and reflections. That's the defintion of $D_{n}$ that I'm working with. So imagine all the elements of $D_{n}$ for some $n$ in a big Cayley table.

Comment: The answer is a little more in-depth now